# Is it more efficient to create an empty dictionary and insert values individually, or to create a dictionary as a single expression?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, dictionary

In Python 3, I wasn't sure which piece of code is more efficient.

Initializing an empty dictionary and adding key, value pairs into it:

```
my_dict = {}
my_dict['a'] = 1
my_dict['b'] = 2
my_dict['c'] = 3
```

Or, initializing a dictionary with all the key, value pairs (assuming of course that the key, value pairs are already known at the time of creation):

```
my_dict = {
    'a': 1,
    'b': 2,
    'c': 3
}
```

Comment: What do you find if you measure the performance of both methods?

Comment: If you really needed to know, you should use `timeit` to get a good time on doing this repeatedly probably with larger dictionaries to be certain, However, looking at the `dis.dis()` of each method, strongly suggests to me that the first is slower. If you want help seeing those results let us know.

Comment: @JonSG : Thanks. I used timeit and see that the first scenario is slower (0.25479018700025335) vs the 2nd one (0.20660465399987515)

Comment: I expect the second code to be always faster than the former. One reason is the re-hashing of the items when the dict is big. Another is the additional overhead of CPython. That being said, the former benefit from a better use of the cache limiting its overheads.

Comment: The second is generally faster, as many people think, but when there are a million elements, the first is actually slightly faster. This is also true for for-loops vs. dict-comprehensions. I know this fact, but I do not know why. I hope someone can answer in detail.

Answer (score 0):

I have assigned the same value 10000 times and got this result.

```
Function 'method1' executed in 0.137408 seconds.
Memory consumption: 0 bytes.
Function 'method2' executed in 0.072864 seconds.
Memory consumption: 0 bytes.
```

From this, I conclude that method 2 is faster than method 1. So it will be **more efficient to create a dictionary as a single expression**.